# How to fetch user ratings with stars in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

The following code has the ability to set a star and pass the number to the database and sets it. However when i refresh the page the stars disappear making it unclear if a user made a review or not.

I would like to be able to fetch the user ratings with the stars that indicate the rating as well.

I'm using a package called [rateable](https://github.com/willvincent/laravel-rateable) and [rateYo](https://github.com/prrashi/rateYo) that allows you to set the stars.

(Below you can set a star just nice and submit will pass it to the database)

[image]

When you referesh you get this

[image]

So im trying to fetch the amount of stars.

here is what i have so far

**Main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        'use strict'

        $('#rateYo').rateYo({
            starWidth: "20px",

        });


        $('#rateYo').click(function(){
            var rating = $('#rateYo').rateYo("rating");
            console.log(rating);

             $('#val').val(rating);


        }); 
       // an ajax function goes here but not sure how to approach this and within the 
      // function i do know that rating needs to be set to the user submitted rating 
      //so that it can fetch the amount of starts
      $('#rateYo').rateYo({
           rating:1-5

        });



});
```

**show.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('rate', $book->id) }}" method="POST">
   {!! csrf_field() !!}

      <div id="rateYo"></div>
      <input name="val" value='' type="hidden" id="val" >

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">submit</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
// this is where im stuck, this is where im attempting to fetch the stars from 
//a user, but im not sure what im doing, i don't how i would pass it in
public function rating($rating)
{
    $book = Book::getRatingAttribute($rating)->userSumRating() ;

    return json_encode($book);
}
```

**Book(model)**

```
public function getRatingAttribute($rating)
{
    return Rateable::where('rating',  $rating )->where('user_id',Auth()->user()->id)->first();
}
```

**Route**

`Route::get('rate/{rating}', 'BookController@rating');`

Any suggestions on how to approach this or how to solve this ?

Answer (score -1):

First print your rating in HTML like this.

```
<div id="rateYo" data-rating="{{ $book->rating }}"></div>
```

Then change javascript to set rating from data attribute:

```
var rating = $('#rateYo').data("rating")
$('#rateYo').rateYo({
            starWidth: "20px",
            rating: rating
        });
```

I think it will work.

Comment: What u mean by worst? This code maybe won't work just copying. Just try to get idea of this.  U will save rating worh div in your html. And when u load rsteyo plugin with rating. Just it. No ajax required

Comment: i don't understand, so i don't need ajax ?